# Display TreeMap with "blank" key at last

Tags: treemap

I have a `TreeMap<String, List<UserVO>>` like this `TreeMap<String, List<UserVO>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, List<UserVO>>(userMap);`

It displays the record with "blank" key first & then it displays ascending.

How can I display as Ascending order & then all records with blank key?

```
List<UserVO> resultList = new ArrayList<UserVO>();  
UserVO userVo = new UserVO();

userVo.setCountry("CountryA");  
userVo.setFirstName("User1");   
resultList.add(userVo);

userVo = new UserVO();
userVo.setCountry("CountryB");  
userVo.setFirstName("User2");   
resultList.add(userVo);

userVo = new UserVO();
userVo.setCountry("");  
userVo.setFirstName("User3");   
resultList.add(userVo);

Then make this List<UserVO> as TreeMap<String, List<CenterVO>>
```

When displaying on UI this TreeMap gives output like :

```
Key = , value = User3
Key = CountryA, value = User1
Key = CountryB, value = User2
```

I want like this:

```
Key = CountryA, value = User1
Key = CountryB, value = User2
Key = , value = User3
```